# How to remove three dots from text-overflow: ellipsis?

Tags: css

I am showing product title inside a `<span>`. I want the title to be truncated when there is no enough space. I tried `text-overflow: clipping`, but its not taking the padding which is applied on right side. So I used `text-overflow: ellipsis`, it works fine, but I don't wanna keep that "..." 3 dots at the end. Is there any way to hide or remove it by css?

Comment: Please post the code in a snippet ([See illustration](http://i.imgur.com/p94EZRA.png?1)), [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [PenCode.io](http://pencode.io), or [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: Please find the jsFiddle... [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sivadass/g9keq8gu/4/#)

Comment: There are a couple of ways to track down an error like this. For example, run your CSS through a linter; or view the element in the style inspector in your debugger. Either way would show you the invalid property value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try clip instead of clipping.

```
text-overflow:clip;
```

=====

EDIT:

This should fix your problem:

```css
.clipping-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #4099ff;
    padding: 0 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.clipping{
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 200px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
}
```

```html
<div class="clipping-wrapper">
  <p class="clipping">
    Copier Paper A4 Size - 70Gsm (500 Sheets)
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sivadass: Okay, hope the edited solution will help.

Comment: Thanks @herrh, it works :) I have one doubt, is it wrong semantic to wrap a single line of text with <span> inside a div??? Please clarify me this if you are free...

Comment: span is an inline element and used to style specific text parts of a paragraph. Can't you use <p> instead of <span> in your project?
PS: Please accept the answer if it shows a working solution.

Comment: Accepted the answer, but am still not clear why I should use <p> instead of <span> tag for a single line of text which is not going to be more than 20-24 Characters...

Comment: You are right. For shorts texts  with 20-24 characters a <span> will be the correct tag.

Answer (score 0):

Made something different

- Eliminated the `text-overflow`
- Made the ' (500 Sheets)' string to [CSS generated content](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter) `a:after { content: ...`
- To hide it it's `font-size: 0`
- On hover, the ' (500 Sheets)' is revealed.

```css
.clip {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #4099ff;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.clip.a:after {
  content: ' (500 Sheets)';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}
.clip.b:after {
  content: ' (Free Recycling)';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}
.clip.c:after {
  content: ' (20 per Box)';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}
.clip.d:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}
.clip:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  padding-right: 80px;
}
.clip:hover:after {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: inherit:
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="clip a">
    Copier Paper A4 Size - 70Gsm
  </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="clip b">
    3M Copy Toner Cartridge - 
  </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="clip c">
    No. 2 Graphite Pencils - 
  </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="clip d">
   Paper Clips - 200 per Box
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Title will vary for each product, so I can't only hide "500 sheets"?

Comment: I'll add different content and see how it looks.

Comment: Fair enough. herth's is the way to go. I came up with the same solution as he did, which is why I took an alternate route.